# How to get the value of a cell when using prettytable

Tags: python, prettytable

Is it possible to get the value of a specific cell when using [prettytable](https://code.google.com/p/prettytable/)?

I have the following code to iterate through all rows of a simple table.

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

table = PrettyTable(["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"])
table.add_row(["A", "B", "C"])
table.add_row(["F", "O", "O"])
table.add_row(["B", "A", "R"])

for row in table:
    print(row)
```

This example prints the following 3 tables:

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
+----------+----------+----------+
|    A     |    B     |    C     |
+----------+----------+----------+
+----------+----------+----------+
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
+----------+----------+----------+
|    F     |    O     |    O     |
+----------+----------+----------+
+----------+----------+----------+
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
+----------+----------+----------+
|    B     |    A     |    R     |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

How is it possible to get only the value of `Column 1`, `Column 2` or `Column 3` of a row?

Comment: Please see the [following link](https://code.google.com/p/prettytable/wiki/Tutorial#Selecting_subsets_of_data).

Comment: This gives me a subset of the table. But how can I get the values of the cells of the defined subset? For example I want to get `A` or `B`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like what you want to do is get a subset of the data, from the [documentation here](https://code.google.com/p/prettytable/wiki/Tutorial#Selecting_subsets_of_data), try:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

table = PrettyTable(["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"])
table.add_row(["A", "B", "C"])
table.add_row(["F", "O", "O"])
table.add_row(["B", "A", "R"])

for row in table:
    print row.get_string(fields=["Column 1"]) # Column 1
```

Edit: It looks like you don't want the headers or border, just the value, in which case, this should work:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

table = PrettyTable(["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"])
table.add_row(["A", "B", "C"])
table.add_row(["F", "O", "O"])
table.add_row(["B", "A", "R"])

for row in table:
    row.border = False
    row.header = False
    print row.get_string(fields=["Column 1"]).strip() # Column 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer version of the prettytable you have the json/svc get:

```
In [13]: json.loads(table.get_json_string())[1]['Column 1']
Out[13]: 'A'
```

OR

```
In [17]: table.get_csv_string(header=False).split(',')[0]
Out[17]: 'A'
```

In the older version

```
In [28]: table[-1].get_string(header=False, fields=['Column 1']).split('|')[1].strip()
Out[28]: 'A'
```

Answer (score -1):

You have the rows method to get access to the raw data

```
table.rows[0][0]   # ="A"
```

Comment: There is no rows method in my PrettyTable

from prettytable import PrettyTable; 
table = PrettyTable(["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"]); 
type(getattr(table, 'rows', None)) # Out[3]: NoneType